# cannot create preview image at lf ( go-Lang filer ) , using imgcat

Tags: macos, lf

I like to create preview image at [lf](https://godoc.org/github.com/gokcehan/lf), go-Lang file manager.
It is possible to create preview image at my manajro-Linux, using [lfimg](https://github.com/cirala/lfimg).

But it is *not* at my Mac, OSX-Mojave.
It is because "[überzug](https://github.com/seebye/ueberzug)", which create preview image, dose not work on OSX.
Then I am trying to use "[imgcat](https://github.com/egoist/imgcat-cli)" and iterm2, build3.4.1, instaed of "überzug".
Because I can create preview, using vifm and imgcat.

Git clone lfimg page and copy preview to ~/.config/lf/, and add following lines to lfrc, which is lf's config file.

```
$ vi lfrc

set previewer ~/.config/lf/preview
```

and modify preview.

```
$ vi preview

# Clear the last preview (if any)
#$HOME/.config/lf/image clear

# Calculate where the image should be placed on the screen.
num=$(printf "%0.f\n" "`echo "$(tput cols) / 2" | bc`")
numb=$(printf "%0.f\n" "`echo "$(tput cols) - $num - 1" | bc`")
numc=$(printf "%0.f\n" "`echo "$(tput lines) - 2" | bc`")

case "$1" in
   *.bmp|*.jpg|*.jpeg|*.png|*.xpm|*.tif|*.gif)
   /usr/local/var/nodebrew/current/bin/imgcat  -w $numb -h $numc "$1"
   ;;
```

But preview image does *not* appear in preview window.
And, [ASCII characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOk8b.jpg) appears instead of image, which seems to mean image.

```
]1337;File=inline=1;width=43;height=49:R0lGODlhbQRSA/cAAA
```

Dose anyone has any good idea to fix this issue?

Thanks,
Yoda

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had much success with imgcat yet, but I was able to get "ascii-fied" previews with chafa:

`chafa --fill=block --symbols=block -c 256 -s 70x"${HEIGHT}" "${FILE}";;`